# Custom "Go" Shortcuts in Lion

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

Under the Go menu, Finder lists keyboard shortcuts for common folders - home (shift + cmd + h), applications (shift + cmd + a), downloads, etc.

I'm looking for a way to define custom keyboard shortcuts for folders I've created that I use often.

I'm aware that in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Application Shortcuts you can define custom shortcuts for any item that appears in the menu of any app on your system.

So I could assign shortcuts to folders under Go > Recent Folders. The problem with this approach is that those folders change dynamically, and so the keyboard shortcuts won't always work.

Is there any other way of going about this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to get system-wide shortcuts to access folders is using the app DefaultFolder.